# Is kurtosis in excess when using the function from pyspark module?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, kurtosis

When using the kurtosis function from the pyspark module `pyspark.sql.functions.kurtosis(col)`, is the result in excess of the Normal distribution? ie. is 3 already subtracted from the kurtosis to yield k-3?
Or would we have to calculate the excess ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but since pyspark gives negative values for its kurtosis, I assume that it is excess kurtosis which it has already subtracted 3 from its calculation.